# Production Calendar - Excel

Tags: excel

I always bite off more than I can chew when it comes to my Excel knowledge. I am hoping someone could help me with this.

Essentially, I have two sheets, first is "Schedule" which is a data dump from MYOB with what we have on order with the warehouse to produce. 
I then go through and plan what needs to be made on what day over a two week period.

I'd then like this to be put in a user friendly calendar in "Plan".
I thought of doing a comcatenate to make the week and day unique, and used an IF And formula. Then i realised all I am doing is making it look for the first line.

Is there a way to do what I am asking in Excel? 
I guess what I want the calendar to look up a category, EG DUCT, then place anything with Duct in the respective concatenated calendar line.

spreadsheet can be found here
http://www.castekauto.net/stack/PlanningSchedulestack.xlsx

TIA

Comment: hi, i've linked to an upload of the spreadsheet. I'm not after anyone to do the work for me, I'd just like to know if it is actually possible, and if so what functions I should be using. Thanks

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, so I don't know how robust the formula is, but it's pretty long... I uploaded a copy of the modified workbook with some changes to the plan worksheet [on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u17836wlygxtmo5/PlanningSchedulestack.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Jerry that is awesome! Wow thank you so much for that, I'm shouting you a coffee! I can't vote you answer though

Comment: @John Thanks a lot for that! I really appreciate it. And that was a comment, I wasn't sure how well that solution would be working for you. I guess I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some changes to the planning table which include:

- Filling column A with Week-Day
- Unmerging the column headers (for Duct for example)
- Standardizing the fields you need (`Composite Hose` changed to `Hose` for example to match the Schedule worksheet)

I used the following array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Table3["&C$6&"]"),SMALL(IF((Table3[Helper]=PLAN!$A7)*(Table3[STOCK CATEGORY]=PLAN!C$5),ROW(Table3[ITEM CODE])-8),ROW(7:7)-MATCH("zzz",$B$1:$B7,1)+1)),"")
```

Sample workbook uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u17836wlygxtmo5/PlanningSchedulestack.xlsx?dl=0).

---

A bit of mumbo jumbo if you want to understand the formula break down a bit:

`IFERROR(Result, "")` simply will show blank if the result is an error (there are no more items that can be displayed)

`INDEX(Column Result,SMALL(Matches, N))` Here `Column Result` is where the result of what we need comes from. It can be Item Code, Description or Quantity. `Matches` is a list of index for the rows that matched some specific criteria (Type of material, whether it's in the same week and day) and `N` is the `N`th result we need. If `N` is 1, then we get the first result of the matches, if `N` is 2, we get the 2nd.

From the above, I used `INDIRECT("Table3["&C$6&"]")` for the Column result to make the formula a bit more flexible. When it is like this, the formula will decide which column it needs to return, whether it's the Item Code, Description or Quantity.

Matches is defined by `IF((Table3[Helper]=PLAN!$A7)*(Table3[STOCK CATEGORY]=PLAN!C$5),ROW(Table3[ITEM CODE])-8)` which basically checks if the week and day matches, together with the Stock Category. If both matches, then return the row number of those rows (the result is an array).

N is defined by `ROW(7:7)-MATCH("zzz",$B$1:$B7,1)+1)`, which is kind of a small algorithm I've used so that after each new day, I get a new N starting at 1, that increments by 1 until a new day is reached. It basically takes the current row, subtract the last row up to the current row from column B and add 1. If the two are on the same row, the result would be 1. If the current row is one row below the last row from column B, the result will be 2, etc.